# Copy file to multiple locations from CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently scanning a directory and **matching file names** and then copying them to various file share locations based upon csv file. The CSV file should have 2 fields: the destination column = path for the copy, and the string Find column = to identify the file to be copied.

My CSV file is like this:

```
"matching file names"      , "Destination"  
"Don"  ,       "c:\test\a"  
"Quest"     , "c:\test\b"
```

Currently it copies all files to all the locations.

Script:

```bsh
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\list.csv"
$filepath = 'C:\Temp\Source'

Get-ChildItem $filepath | foreach {
  $criteria = $csv
  $find = $csv | select -ExpandProperty find

  $a = $_.FullName
  foreach ($f in $find) {
    if ($a -like "*$f*") {
      foreach ($c in $criteria) {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $c.Destination
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing there's no column "find" in your CSV. I'm going to assume that the column you titled "matching file names" actually has the title "find".

Your problem is caused by the nested double loop in your code. You iterate over each pattern, then copy all files matching a given pattern to every destination from the CSV with the innermost loop.

Use just one loop for the CSV data (to keep the association between filter string and destination path intact), and the problem will disappear. I'd also recommend using the `Contains()` method instead of the `-like` operator, so you don't need to add wildcards to the filter string.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem $filepath | ForEach-Object {
  foreach ($filter in $csv) {
    if ($f.Name.Contains($filter.find)) {
      Copy-Item $_.FullName $filter.Destination
    }
  }
}
```